# Can I go back to Dreamy areas once I have rescued the Pi'ilo inside them?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

I realized after rescuing a Pi'illo from a Dreamy area that I missed one of the Attack Pieces, and kinda want to go back to get it because, well, having more moves is always good.

I only realized this much later, though, so I don't want to go all the way back to the area I was in if I can't get the piece I want - so is it possible for me to get back to particular Dreamy areas? Or are they closed off once the Pi'illo is rescued?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can talk to the resuscitated Pi'illos - IIRC one of the options in the conversation is "Take me to the Dream World", which will let you re-enter the level.

Answer (score 0):

If you go back to the Pi'llo, he will ask you if you want to go back to the Dream World. Answer “Yes" and he will transport you back to the dream world.